# python wildcard import

Tags: python, import, wildcard

Strange problem when importing modules:

File structure:

```
pages/
      test.py
spawn.py
```

From spawn.py, if I do

```
from pages import test
```

everything works as expected.

If I do

```
from pages import *
```

I get

```
NameError: name 'test' is not defined
```

I don't get ImportError. I have commented out everything but two lines of code. I have **init**.py in the 'pages' dir, not that is should matter since I'm able to import just not use. I have tried changing filenames. Have tried on different machines, both Debian 6.0 though. Python version 2.6.6

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It matters because the `pages/__init__.py` contains the symbols which `from pages import *` will import

Comment: I see. So the wildcard not really worth using since you'll have to define what to import anyways? Guess I'll skip it altogether.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put `import test` in `pages/__init__.py`.

Just because `pages` is a module does not mean it magically imports all the files in the same folder. You still have to name the modules you want to import (or write code that imports them automatically).

Comment: You mean that pages is a package.